# MySQL : IS NOT NULL check on custom generated column(alias)

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, where-clause, alias, notnull

The stored procedure is working fine till now , but I want records **only when** `dist_calculated` `IS NOT NULL`. When I use that condition in `where clause` , it shows error `#1054 - Unknown column 'dist_calculated' in 'where clause'`. Witout where clause it runs well and returns NULL records too like :

```
entity_id   dist_calculated     
49              NULL
50              NULL
52              4460.615
51              4875.179
```

And I want to exclude NULL.

I tried `WHERE dist_calculated IS NOT NULL` and `WHERE cpe.dist_calculated IS NOT NULL` still gives error.

My stored procedure is :

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE get_close_childcares(IN latUser DECIMAL(15,6),IN lngUser DECIMAL(15,6) )
BEGIN
    /*Get 4 ids of closest childcares*/
    /*Outer query   
    @param : userLat, userLng, Current childcare lat,current childcare lng
    Note : Inner query returns lat , lng of Current product 176 : lat , 177: lng
    */
    SELECT cpe.entity_id , get_distance_in_miles_between_geo_locations(latUser,lngUser,
        (SELECT cpev.value FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar AS cpev 
            WHERE (cpev.entity_id = cpe.entity_id AND cpev.attribute_id = 176)
        ),
        (SELECT cpev.value FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar AS cpev 
            WHERE (cpev.entity_id = cpe.entity_id AND cpev.attribute_id = 177)
        )
    ) AS dist_calculated
    FROM catalog_product_entity AS cpe
    WHERE dist_calculated IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY dist_calculated ASC
    LIMIT 0,4;

END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

And call to the stored procedure :

`call get_close_childcares(19.992100,73.777000)`

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL does allow use of the column aliases on GROUP BY and HAVING but not in WHERE statements. Therefore you need to use the full definition in WHERE, e.g.

```
SELECT cpe.entity_id , get_distance_in_miles_between_geo_locations(latUser,lngUser,
    (SELECT cpev.value FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar AS cpev 
        WHERE (cpev.entity_id = cpe.entity_id AND cpev.attribute_id = 176)
    ),
    (SELECT cpev.value FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar AS cpev 
        WHERE (cpev.entity_id = cpe.entity_id AND cpev.attribute_id = 177)
    )
) AS dist_calculated
FROM catalog_product_entity AS cpe
WHERE
get_distance_in_miles_between_geo_locations(latUser,lngUser,
        (SELECT cpev.value FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar AS cpev 
            WHERE (cpev.entity_id = cpe.entity_id AND cpev.attribute_id = 176)
        ),
        (SELECT cpev.value FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar AS cpev 
            WHERE (cpev.entity_id = cpe.entity_id AND cpev.attribute_id = 177)
        )
    ) IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY dist_calculated ASC
LIMIT 0,4;
```

Comment: Can you please let me know `what could be done here then `?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this mate:

```
SELECT
    cpe.entity_id,
    get_distance_in_miles_between_geo_locations (
        latUser,
        lngUser,
        cpev_1.`value`,
        cpev_2.`value`
    ) AS dist_calculated
FROM
    catalog_product_entity cpe
    INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar cpev_1 ON cpev_1.entity_id = cpe.entity_id
        AND cpev_1.attribute_id = 176
    INNER JOIN catalog_product_entity_varchar cpev_2 ON cpev_2.entity_id = cpev.entity_id
        AND cpev_2.attribute_id = 177
ORDER BY
    dist_calculated ASC
LIMIT 0,4;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
CREATE PROCEDURE get_close_childcares(IN latUser DECIMAL(15,6),IN lngUser DECIMAL(15,6) )
BEGIN
    /*Get 4 ids of closest childcares*/
    /*Outer query   
    @param : userLat, userLng, Current childcare lat,current childcare lng
    Note : Inner query returns lat , lng of Current product 176 : lat , 177: lng
    */
    SELECT cpe.entity_id , get_distance_in_miles_between_geo_locations(latUser,lngUser,
        (SELECT cpev.value FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar AS cpev 
            WHERE (cpev.entity_id = cpe.entity_id AND cpev.attribute_id = 176)
        ),
        (SELECT cpev.value FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar AS cpev 
            WHERE (cpev.entity_id = cpe.entity_id AND cpev.attribute_id = 177)
        )
    ) AS dist_calculated
    FROM catalog_product_entity AS cpe
    WHERE get_distance_in_miles_between_geo_locations(latUser,lngUser,
        (SELECT cpev.value FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar AS cpev 
            WHERE (cpev.entity_id = cpe.entity_id AND cpev.attribute_id = 176)
        ),
        (SELECT cpev.value FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar AS cpev 
            WHERE (cpev.entity_id = cpe.entity_id AND cpev.attribute_id = 177)
        )
    ) IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY dist_calculated ASC
    LIMIT 0,4;

END
```

Comment: Not working , generating Stored procedure for it gives error